# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown submenu background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a little trouble with background color of my dropdown menu. I changed the color of background color on hover to orange. But, if I go to any submenu in that dropdown, the color of parent item change to default blue. Don't know, how to explain it better, I will just show a picture:

[image: TWB Submenu]

So, as soon as I hover over subitem, the parent background color change to blue. I was trying to do a selector for that but ran out of ideas. Any help please?

Comment: How did you change the background-color to orange? Code please?

Comment: .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: none;
    filter: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need something like this to ensure all CSS selectors are covered...

```
/* change background color on hover */
.dropdown-submenu > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu > a:hover, .dropdown-submenu:focus>a, r, .dropdown-submenu:hover>a,
.dropdown-menu > li a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li a:focus { background-color: orange; background-image: none; filter: none; text-decoration: none; border: none; }
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/75155